# How do I flip all zeroes and ones in a number, but only 1 digit at a time in Python3?

Tags: python

e.g.
when 1010 is the given number,
i want it to output:

```
0010
1110
1000
1011
```

I have tried to do it without imports to challenge myself. I've tried to put each number in a list and flip each digit accordingly. I get stuck when it doesn't update the first number. It outputs:

```
0010
0110
0000
0011
```

Comment: Interesting question.  Don't forget to post your current attempt *code* and where do you get stuck?

Comment: It seems that the algorithm you tried it's flipping its own output instead of the original list. Can you modify it so it doesn't update the original data?

Comment: You say "I have tried to do it without imports to challenge myself" - please share those attempts, so people can get a sense of where you're at, what you already understand and what may help you the most.

Comment: Do you get `1010` as a string i.e. `'1010'`, or defined as a binary representation of an integer i.e. `0b1010`?

Answer (score 4):

Binary numbers represent a number as a sum of powers of 2 written from right to left (just like decimal numbers represent a number as a sum of powers of 10 written from right to left).

If you get your value as a string (`'1010'`) you can turn it into an integer, if you get it as an integer (`0b1010`) you of course wouldn't need to:

```
value = '1010'
x = int(value, 2)  # interpret string as binary

a = 1
while a < x:
    print(x ^ a, '{0:04b}'.format(x ^ a))
    a = a * 2
```

This line:

```
print(x ^ a, '{0:04b}'.format(x ^ a))
```

It prints `x ^ a`, which is the logical XOR of `x` and `a`, meaning that it will have a `1` wherever `x` and `a` are different, and `0` elsewhere. Since `a` will be a power of 2, it will only have 1 bit set to 1, and so it will flip just that bit.

The second part starts with `'{0:04b}'`, which will format the same value as binary, using 4 positions.

If you don't like that it's reversed, you'd need to know where to start (i.e. the greatest power of 2 that still fits into the number), but that is a given if you know the length of the string you want:

```
value = '1010'
x = int(value, 2)  # interpret string as binary

for a in range(len(value)-1, -1, -1):
    print(x ^ 2**a, '{0:04b}'.format(x ^ 2**a))
```

Or, as a one-liner:

```
value = '1010'
print(' '.join(f'{int(value, 2) ^ 2**a:04b}' for a in range(len(value)-1, -1, -1)))
```

These two examples loop through powers of 2, starting at the greatest power of two that fits inside the starting value, down to `2^0` (`1`) and perform the same trick as before.

The one-liner then also puts the results together with spaces, as in your example.

Outputs:

```
2 0010
14 1110
8 1000
11 1011

0010 1110 1000 1011
```

Comment: It outputs the numbers in reverse order.

Comment: Very nice and detail explanations.  Prob. it's too *dense* for those unitiated to digest all at once.  Upvote.  (TIL - refresh the bit ops)

Comment: I see what you mean @DanielHao, although explaining one level down would make for a very long answer, and just providing a solution that manipulats strings is teaching bad programming in my opinion - I went with this because I figure this gets OP to look at the elements the exercise is trying to teach, without spelling it out.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is to convert string to list, replace the required index and convert it back to the string.

```
s = "1010"
res = []
for i in range(0, len(s)):
    t = list(s)
    t[i] = '1' if t[i] == '0' else '0'
    res.append(''.join(t))
print(res) #['0010', '1110', '1000', '1011']
```

Comment: Whether it's "simple" is open to discussion, but it's certainly not very efficient, given that CPUs are literally built to do these types of operations efficiently on integer types.

Comment: @Grismar Judging by my answer's benchmark, those integer solutions are also not very fast :-P

Comment: More to do with the string formatting that follows, that your solution eschews. But I'm sure you already knew that.

Comment: @Grismar Well, that's part of your solution. I didn't know it had *more* to do with that, as I hadn't measured the parts separately. Job half done doesn't count :-). Btw for small input, this solution is about as fast as yours, and a little optimization doubles its speed. And yours would likely slow down a little further if you fixed them (both hardcore the output length as 4, and the first one doesn't produce all outputs for example for inputs `'1000'` and `'0'`).

Answer (score 1):

```
N = 345678909876543223456
for i in range(N.bit_length()):
   print(N^(1<<i))
```

You can use simple bitwise operators:

`^` is Xor, basically `bit^1` flips the bit

`<<` is a left shift, basically `1<<N` appends N zero in front of the bit -> 1000...Ntimes

Answer (score 1):

Since Grismar brought up efficiency, here's a benchmark on a larger input (`'1010' * 3000`) with two more solutions:

```
 210 ms  Grismar1
 345 ms  Grismar2
2043 ms  Akshay
  52 ms  Kelly1
  13 ms  Kelly2
```

For better comparison I made all solutions generators that yield the strings.

Full code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZPPjpswEMbveYqRqpVN1o2A7KFC5dBTD32EVTayYdh41zbUdtqgqs@e2kASwmmlIiFgJv6@3/xJ1/tDa7ZfOns@19jAD1Sqz6hLihWEq2ktSAYVSANojhot93jNxquXqGpwz4XcwSNQkhGQTThQlkBSAqgcxpckJN2zfMyK3Wp1NcqvUsJBCaL3yK3lPXUMCHeVlCSZc4h7DjEHEUF@By8lZAs24TY1Vm2NNFn8ODiOMN@tdJrbjP7i6oiT6CnkpfFjjEGeAHyKAbSdRQ/OW2legTsQ0nDbD2c4XPx/H6TC8P21hNOiW@RPWqRP4i/ZhLI09/QEL8BvcFGEwxryO7j8v@FiE3nsoOXmFalCM0l@zhiMd/IR1Hy9DrQD27d3d4jjmq/LzSFlEE1cMpP1AVxJ50P0FhuHMe3O@HW/PouRErJ5a6WhPmA0R1PF5bnMkF0bxiY8Nm319AxtjZxN5BwOj3Cdjf1cN2GF0ywsLINms98brnG/jza21eClRulB6q61Hix2yP2YqVqlsPKyNe6SrvHnEZdecayj39D6oepoF@LbNE1XlxbpUN2oTxXXoubFqEebaWYM0nCHv4JAW2ZJMquBPDzVoB0QeADqg3KG2/tyzud/)):

```
def Kelly1(s):
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        yield s[:i] + ('1' if c == '0' else '0') + s[i+1:]

def Kelly2(s):
    bs = bytearray(s, 'ascii')
    for i, b in enumerate(bs):
        bs[i] ^= 1
        yield bs.decode()
        bs[i] = b

def Grismar1(value):
    x = int(value, 2)  # interpret string as binary
    a = 1
    while a <= x:
        yield'{0:04b}'.format(x ^ a)
        a = a * 2

def Grismar2(value):
    x = int(value, 2)  # interpret string as binary
    for a in range(len(value)-1, -1, -1):
        yield'{0:04b}'.format(x ^ 2**a)

def Akshay(s):
    for i in range(0, len(s)):
        t = list(s)
        t[i] = '1' if t[i] == '0' else '0'
        yield ''.join(t)

funcs = Grismar1, Grismar2, Akshay, Kelly1, Kelly2

for f in funcs:
    print(*f('1010'), f.__name__)

from timeit import repeat
from collections import deque

for f in funcs * 2:
    value = '1010' * 3000
    t = min(repeat(lambda: deque(f(value), 0), number=1))
    print('%4d ms ' % (t * 1e3), f.__name__)
```